# Linux zip up all log files

Tags: linux

I'm trying to zip up all .log files in a my log directory. I want to zip each log file individually and keep it in the same directory, then delete the original. I'm somewhat new to using Linux and for loops in Linux. Here is the for loop I'm trying to run

```
ssh user@SERVER "for i in *.log; do zip -m \"${i%.*}.zip\" \"${i%.*}\".*; done"
```

What ended up happening is all of my hidden files got zipped up. Like I said, I'm kinda new so, whatever syntax error I made isn't jumping out at me. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `$` needs to be escaped tooo. To manage and compress log files, use logrotate , nowadays just use journalctl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you were near)

```
ssh user@SERVER 'for i in *.log; do echo zip -m "\${i/.log/.zip}" "\${i}"; done'
```

If the output seems correct, remove the `echo`

Comment: The command itself worked perfectly, but due to how single and double quotes work (atleast I think that was the issue), I had to modify it ever so slightly: `user@$SERVER "for i in *.log; do echo zip -m \"\${i/.log/.zip}\" \"\${i}\"; done"`